# Is there a way to check if a class is convertible to some template instantiation?

Tags: c++, templates

### The question

Here some code

```cpp
struct Base
{
    int SomeMethod(const Base&);
    template <class T> int SomeMethod(const T&);
};

template <class Tag> struct Derived : Base
{
    using Base::SomeMethod;
    int SomeMethod(const Derived&);
    template <class OtherTag> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<Tag, OtherTag>> SomeMethod(Derived<OtherTag>) = delete;
};

struct tag {};
struct another_tag {};

struct ImplicitOpToAnotherTagInstantiation { operator Derived<another_tag>() const; };
```

Is there something (`Derived::SomeMethod` overload) that i can write in `Derived` without touching the `Base`, that will cause a compiler error in the next code?

```cpp
Derived<tag>{}.SomeMethod(ImplicitOpToAnotherTagInstantiation {});
```

Next code should be correct

```cpp
struct ImplicitOpToBase { operator Base() const; };

Derived<tag>{}.SomeMethod(Derived<tag>{});
Derived<tag>{}.SomeMethod(Base{});
Derived<tag>{}.SomeMethod(ImplicitOpToBase{});
// Derived<tag>{}.SomeMethod(Derived<another_tag>{}); compiler error!
```

### What have I tried

- First thought was to do something like this:

```cpp
template <class Tag> struct Derived : Base
{
    using Base::SomeMethod;
    int SomeMethod(const Derived&);
    template <class OtherTag> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<Tag, OtherTag>> SomeMethod(Derived<OtherTag>) = delete;
    template <class T, class OtherTag> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<Tag, OtherTag> && std::is_convertible<Tag, Derived<OtherTag>>> SomeMethod(T) = delete;
};
```

But it doesn't work because there is no way for compiler to deduce `OtherTag`, without explicit instantiation like this

```cpp
Derived<tag>{}.SomeMethod<ImplicitOpToAnotherTagInstantiation, another_tag>(); // error: deleted function!
```

- Second thought:

```cpp
template <class Tag> struct Derived : Base
{
    using Base::SomeMethod;
    int SomeMethod(const Derived&);
    template <class OtherTag> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<Tag, OtherTag>> SomeMethod(Derived<OtherTag>) = delete;
    template <class T> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<T, Derived> && std::is_convertible<T, Base>> SomeMethod(T) = delete;
};
```

But next code results in compiler error, when shouldn't:

```cpp
Derived<tag>{}.SomeMethod(ImplicitOpToBase{});
```

### Main usage

I am trying to create some kind of a strong typedef for `std::string` where `Base` is `std::string`, `Derived` is my `TaggedString`, `SomeMethod` is `std::string::assign`. I want to disable `assign` method with types of another tag and I have some difficulties explained in the question. For the sake of the reader i am omitting the fact, that `TaggedString` is implicitly convertible to `std::string_view`.

```cpp
template <class Tag> struct TaggedString : std::string
{
    using std::string::assign;
    TaggedString& assign(const TaggedString& other) { std::string::assign(other); return *this; }
    template <class OtherTag> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<Tag, OtherTag>> assign(TaggedString<OtherTag>) = delete;
};
```

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/5nocben88) is something to play with.

Comment: Please explain the problem, not what solution you expect to get. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There's an infinite set of possible conversions, even an infinite set of conversions to `Derived<SomeUnknownType>`. Your compiler cannot test every possible type T to see if `ImplicitOpToAnotherTagInstantiation` is perhaps convertible to `Derived<T>`.

It could test a finite set, if you provide that. But you only have `tag`, a type to **exclude**. An infinite set of types minus one type is still an infinite set of types.

Comment: I am trying to check whether the `T` (that I am passing to `Derived<tag>::SomeMethod`) is convertible to `Derived<U>` with `U` anything but `tag`. It seems like the compiler needs to check only the presence of `Derived<tag>` in the `T`, but i could be wrong

Comment: @SherAndrei: I think you're wrong, because it appears you assume there's only a single conversion sequence. There can be multiple `operator Derived<Something>` , so the presence of  `operator Derived<tag>`  does not exclude other operators.

Comment: If there are multiple `operator Derived<Something>` and one of them is `operator Derived<tag>` can't the compiler choose the most fitting one (`operator Derived<tag>`)?

Comment: Of course, that's easy. In fact, the compiler will also try other solutions, such as `Derived<Tag>::Derived(ImplicitOpTagInstantiation)`. But you seem to mix the detection of one thing and the detection of the absence of another. It appears you want to disable some assignments, when the usual solution is to rely on overloading to pick the best match.